# Displaying 1.10 as NUMBER and not Characters

Tags: sql, oracle, numbers

I try the below query

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(1.10)
FROM DUAL;
```

The result was 1.1. It is possible that I can get this to display as 1.10 in number using TO_NUMBER function instead of using TO_CHAR function? This is because all the variables and cursor to store this were declare as NUMBER datatype and I do not wanted to change the declaration (as it will impact a lot of packages)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Passing a number to `to_number()` doesn't do anything except implicitly convert it to a string before converting it back to a number. Your client decides how to display numbers, and most clients let you specify (e.g. in SQL\*Plus, `set numformat` and more focused `columns` formatting). If your own application is displaying the number then it should do the formatting for display.

Answer (score 0):

TO_NUMBER() converts text to number. Number is usually not used for display but for calculations and saved data.

TO_CHAR() converts data to text (overloaded function), where you can control how your text looks like.

So TO_NUMBER(1.10) doesn't really do anything since you are converting a number to a number.

So when displaying a number (not a text) oracle does an implicit conversion to text using default display values. So you should always use to_char to control the display of number.

Take a look at this example:

```
declare
   l_number   number := 1.10;
   l_text     varchar2 (10) := '200.20';
begin
   dbms_output.put_line (l_number);
   dbms_output.put_line (to_char (l_number, '9D00'));
   dbms_output.put_line (l_text);
   dbms_output.put_line (to_number (l_text));
end;
```

outputs:

```
1.1
 1.10
200.20
200.2
```

You see that to_char adds a space padding to the formatting. So you should use **trim()** if you don't want that.